# Shared method between two classes

Tags: c++, database, qt, oop

I'm trying to share a method between two classes, where each one is using its private attribute, like this :

```
class DbWriter {
public:
    int GetIdFromDB(QString codVEI)        //<! uses mDbWriteQuery
private:
    QSqlQuery mDbWriteQuery;
}


class DbReader {
public:
    int GetIdFromDB(QString codVEI)        //<! uses mDbReadQuery
private:
    QSqlQuery mDbReadQuery;
}
```

I want to make something like a friend method, but with each one knowing their own attribute member, and without having to create a class and inherit from it these two classes because it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: *it doesn't work in my case* - you should clarify this statement. Inheritance is essentially the only way to share methods between classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using polymorphic classes. E.g.

```
class DbObject
{
public:
  virtual int GetIdFromDB(const QString &codVEI) = 0;
private:
  QSqlQuery mQuery;
};

class DbWriter : public DbObject
{
public:
  int GetIdFromDB(const QString &codVEI) override;
};

class DbReader : public DbObject
{
public:
  int GetIdFromDB(const QString &codVEI) override;
};
```

Usage:

```
auto dbObject = std::make_shared<DbWriter>();
int id = dbObject->GetIdFromDB("foo"); // Calls write query

dbObject = std::make_shared<DbReader>();
id = dbObject->GetIdFromDB("foo"); // Calls read query
```

**Update**

Fixed the `DbReader` class declaration - it should also derive from `DbObject` class.

Comment: I had to change the conception to be able to implement this solution. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share an implementation just use a common free function:

```
namespace detail {
  int GetIdFromDB(QString codVEI, QSqlQuery const& query); 
}
```

Include/link it with both classes and have them call it.

Passing the query as a parameter avoids senseless coupling by not introducing friendship into the mix.